# Cross Entropy Loss function not converging

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I'm new to neural networks and I'm building one that reads handwritten numbers. The losses float around 2.2-2.3 and I'm not sure why it's not converging. I tried messing with the learning rate but it doesn't really do anything.

```
# TODO: Define function to create our own neural network

# Parameters
input_size = 784    # Hint: image size is 28x28, and we want to flatten the image 
num_classes = 10   # Hint: our inputs include 0-9
num_epochs = 5    # Number of times we loop through the entire training dataset, can be pretty arbitrary

class NN(nn.Module):
  ############ YOUR CODE STARTS HERE ############
  # 1. Initialize our own NN model
  def __init__(self, input_size, num_classes):
    super(NN, self).__init__()
    self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
    # Use ReLU activation function
    self.relu = nn.ReLU()  
    # Input layer
    self.input_layer = nn.Linear(input_size, 13)  
    # Hidden layers: use at least 1 hidden layer!
    self.hidden1 =  nn.Linear(13, 6) 
    # Output layer
    self.output_layer = nn.Linear(6, 10)
  
  # 2. Define method for forwarding input data
  def forward(self, sample):

    sample = self.flatten(sample)
    out = self.input_layer(sample)  
    out = self.relu(out)  

    out = self.hidden1(out)  
    out = self.relu(out)  #TODO: activation function

    out = self.output_layer(out) #TODO: forward to output layer
    return out
  
nn_model = NN(input_size, num_classes)
print("My NN Model: ", nn_model)
```

Loss function:

```
loss_function = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()  
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(nn_model.parameters(), lr=.0001)
```

Training:

```
total_steps = len(train_loader)
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
  for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
    # Reshape our images from 2D(28x28) to 1D(784)
    images = images.view(-1, 28*28).to(device)   
    labels = labels.to(device) 

    # Call functions we've previously defined to perform forward pass & calculate loss
    output = nn_model.forward(images) 
    loss = loss_function(output, labels)   

    # Backward pass
    optimizer.zero_grad()  
    loss.backward() 
      # calculates gradients
    optimizer.step() 

    # Print out training process
    if (i+1) % 100 == 0:
      print(f'epoch {epoch+1} / {num_epochs}, step {i+1}/{total_steps}, loss = {loss.item():.4f}')
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How does it work on your data, did it learn something? Maybe it converged very fast before you have seen your loss, I mean it might trained well on 100 batches if you have a large batch size.

Comment: @AnvarGaniev Hi, I'm not sure what you mean, but to clarify for the losses I get the output of : 
`epoch 1 / 5, step 100/3750, loss = 2.3609` and 
`epoch 5 / 5, step 3700/3750, loss = 2.2475`    so it didn't seem to change much even from the very first one,     unless you mean it converged before step 100?